# How to get array format data from json data in laravel4 query builder?

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I am using laravel4 query builder . I have following query which returns json data .

```
$query=DB::connection('mysqlMagento')->
    table('magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1')->
    join('sohyper_region_activity', 'magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.entity_id', '=', 'sohyper_region_activity.activity_id')->
    select("magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.entity_id" , "magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.parent_id" , "magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.name as label" ,"magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.url_key as name")->
    get();
```

The above query returns json format data , I want to convert this to arrat format . I know Toarray() is used in eloquent to convert this but here it is in query builder , please help me on this .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query=DB::connection('mysqlMagento')->
    table('magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1')->
    join('sohyper_region_activity', 'magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.entity_id', '=', 'sohyper_region_activity.activity_id')->
    select("magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.entity_id" , "magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.parent_id" , "magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.name as label" ,"magento_catalog_category_flat_store_1.url_key as name")->
    get();

$array = json_decode($query);
```

Though i'm fairly sure that the query builder is not returning JSON.

Comment: It returns object form and I want to convert this to same as Toarray() does in laravel eloquent .

Comment: $obj = $query; $array = (array) $obj;

Answer (score 0):

The query builder returns an array of objects. For example the query:

```
$users = DB::table('users')->select('name')->get();
```

will return an array which you can handle like this

```
foreach($users as $user) {

    echo $user->name;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to convert it to array you have to do it on your own.

Here is a quick way

```
$users = json_decode(json_encode($users), true);
```

Now you can handle it like this

```
foreach($users as $user) {

    echo $user['name'];
}
```

Comment: I want the same result as Toarray() gives with eloquent .